# Generators of free Boolean algebras

Tags: boolean-algebra, universal-algebra

Suppose $\mathfrak{A}$ is a free Boolean algebra and $G$ a countable set of free generators of $\mathfrak{A}$.

1. What is the cardinality of $\mathfrak{A}$ if $G$ is **countably infinite**, but we only allow **finite** unions and intersections of elements of $G$?
2. What is the cardinality of $\mathfrak{A}$ $G$ is **countably infinite**, but if this time we allow **countably infinite** unions and intersections of elements of $G$?

Comment: In general, for 1., a (free) algebra (freely) generated by an infinite set $X$ in a variety of the first-order language $\mathcal{L}$   has cardinality $\leq\max(|X|,|\mathcal{L}|)$. In this case, since $\mathcal{L}$ is finite, the cardinality is exactly $\aleph_0$.

Comment: Thanks Pedro for the reply. Could you please point me towards a reference for the result you mention. Also, you consider first-order languages. Is there any difference for zero-order language? Thanks.

Comment: The (freely available) book [A Course in Universal Algebra](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/ualg.html) contains all the basics of the subject. I'm not used to the terminology “zero-order” language, but a first-order one has only finitary operations (and relations), but not infinitary ones as infinite unions.